Pretty print why two objects are not equal
When using pytest, I get nice pretty printing when two objects are not equivalent:
Expected :Foo(id='red', other_thing='green')
Actual   :Foo(id='red', other_thing='blue')
<Click to see difference>

def test_baz():
    
        oneFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="blue")
        twoFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="green")
    
>       assert oneFoo == twoFoo
E       AssertionError: assert Foo(id='red', other_thing='blue') == Foo(id='red', other_thing='green')
E         
E         Full diff:
E         - Foo(id='red', other_thing='green')
E         ?                            ^^ --
E         + Foo(id='red', other_thing='blue')
E         ?                            ^^^

baz.py:22: AssertionError

If I use an assert directly in my code, I just get an AssertionError and a stacktrace.
I am writing some integration tests right now that are NOT driven by pytest but would like to pretty print when two items (specifically Pydantic dataclasses) are not equal.

Can you clarify what output you're expecting? The stacktrace shown isn't enough information?

This works pretty well:
from difflib import Differ

import structlog
from colorama import Fore
from pydantic import BaseModel

logger = structlog.getLogger(__name__)

def check_equals(expected: BaseModel, actual: BaseModel) -> None:
    if not expected == actual:

        logger.error("Objects are not equal", expected=expected, actual=actual)

        diff_output = Differ().compare(
            _get_lines(expected),
            _get_lines(actual)
        )

        color_diff_output = _color_diff(diff_output)

        print("\n".join(color_diff_output))

        raise ValueError("Objects not equal")

def _get_lines(item: BaseModel) -> str:
    item_json = item.model_dump_json(indent=4)
    lines = item_json.splitlines()
    return lines

def _color_diff(diff):
    """
    Found this nice function here: https://chezsoi.org/lucas/blog/colored-diff-output-with-python.html
    """
    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('+'):
            yield Fore.GREEN + line + Fore.RESET
        elif line.startswith('-'):
            yield Fore.RED + line + Fore.RESET
        elif line.startswith('^'):
            yield Fore.BLUE + line + Fore.RESET
        else:
            yield line

Prints:

When you run this code:
from pydantic import BaseModel

from util.integration_test_validation.check_equals import check_equals

class Bar(BaseModel):
    beaches: int
    oranges: int

class Foo(BaseModel):
    id: str
    other_thing: str
    count: int
    bar: Bar



oneFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="blue", count=3, bar=Bar(beaches=5, oranges=7))
twoFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="green", count=3, bar=Bar(beaches=5, oranges=7))

check_equals(oneFoo, twoFoo)


The equality should be implement using __eq__:
For example:
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Foo):
            return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))


a = Foo(1, 2)
b = Foo(1, 2)
c = Foo(3, 4)

print(a == b)
print(a == c)

my_dict = {a: 'value 1', c: 'value 3'}
print(my_dict[a])


Prints:
True
False
value 1


Note
hash() is not required in this context. But it is a good practice to implement that.
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))


In your code, in fact, those objects are not equal, hence the AssertionError. If you want to rewrite that, with anything, with your own custom errors, or anything else , then you have to add that in your eq method.
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, id, other_thing):
        self.id = id
        self.other_thing = other_thing

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Foo):
            return self.id == other.id and self.other_thing == other.other_thing
        return False


def test_baz():
    oneFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="blue")
    twoFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="green")
    try:
        assert oneFoo == twoFoo
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError(f"{oneFoo.__dict__} and {twoFoo.__dict__} are not equal.")


test_baz()




Prints
    raise ValueError(f"{oneFoo.__dict__} and {twoFoo.__dict__} are not equal.")
ValueError: {'id': 'red', 'other_thing': 'blue'} and {'id': 'red', 'other_thing': 'green'} are not equal.


You can also implement any styling that you wanna give:
from pprint import pprint


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, id, other_thing):
        self.id = id
        self.other_thing = other_thing

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Foo):
            return self.id == other.id and self.other_thing == other.other_thing
        return False


def test_baz():
    oneFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="blue")
    twoFoo = Foo(id="red", other_thing="green")
    try:
        assert oneFoo == twoFoo
    except AssertionError:
        print("The objects are not equal:")
        A, B = oneFoo.__dict__, twoFoo.__dict__
        for k, v in A.items():
            if A[k] != B[k]:
                len_val_a = (len(A[k]) + 2) * "^"
                len_val_b = (len(B[k]) + 2) * "^"
                # pprint(f"Object {A} != Object {B}")
                pprint(f"{A[k]} != {B[k]}")
                print(f"{len_val_a}   {len_val_a}")
        return


test_baz()



Prints
The objects are not equal:
'blue != green'
^^^^^^   ^^^^^^



This doesn't print ^^^ underneath the bits that differ, which I think was the main point of the question.

@JohnGordon Really? That was the main point. Ha! Let me check.

@JohnGordon You may be right. But it seems to me that the OP does not seem to know that an AssertionError is totally valid. That ^^^ can be programmed, once the OP would realize where the core problem is.

@JohnGordon Here in the "simulated" ValueError(), I printed the dicts. They can code using that: ValueError: {'id': 'red', 'other_thing': 'blue'} and {'id': 'red', 'other_thing': 'green'} are not equal. 

Found a pretty nice solution - see above :)

@JohnGordon You were right. Updated for that.
